# Light working after washing machine has run

Tags: electrical, wiring

An electrician has looked at this and said it is legal because it was up to code when it was made. But if changes are done to it, it must be up to the current code. I will have it fixed by the same electrician, but I want to understand how the following can happen.
He also told me a bit about the wiring which I have illustrated here.

[image: Wires and switches]

The switch at C turns on the lamp in the ceiling E.

The switch at D can turn on an additional lamp, but nothing is currently hooked up to that outlet.

The switches at A and B each turn on the outlet under them.

Everything was working as it should.

I hooked up a few things at A and B (such as a vacuum cleaner). Everything was still working fine.

I hooked up a charger for a laptop at B. The light at E flashed on and off for a few seconds and then turned off. I thought it was the bulb, but that was not the case (I have checked that several times - the issue is never the bulb).
The situation - neither A, B or E is working. I checked and could see *some* current was flowing when I switched them on, but I don't have the tools to see how much.

I left the switch at C turned on even though it had no effect.

Suddenly, the lamp at E worked again. C could be turned on and off and it worked as expected. I was puzzled.

Stupid as I was, I plugged something into A again. E stopped working again.

I left C turned on again hoping it would start working again. Suddenly, the light turned on. I noticed it turned on while the washing machine was running at its loudest. Once the washing machine stopped, E turned off again. This pattern repeated two more times. The fourth time, C worked again without the need for the washing machine being on.

Even more puzzled I decided not to touch A or B since I now had working light at E. However, I had to turn off F to do work on something else. Once again E has stopped working, still has some current running through it. It no longer seems to be effected by the washing machine.

I have checked all the places I can and there is no loose connections.

I cannot figure out how all this is effecting each other, and I am quite puzzled by it. How can this be?
I can add further explanations and pictures if that is needed.

Comment: Changes to the circuit and fixing what is there are two different things, usually.  It seems like it might be a three way circuit(two switches control one or more lights).  If the circuit is safe as is, and only needs a connection or two tighten up, it should not be much work, and should be able to be left as is.  If unsafe and/or needs more work, then it must be brought up to code.

Comment: @crip659 Due to maintenance in other rooms, changes must be done anyway.